# How to navigate dynamic pages?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

The following code

```
export default async function getVehicleDetail(vehicleId: string) {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://brainy-clothes-fish.cyclic.app/api/v1/vehicles/${vehicleId}`,
    { next: { revalidate: 60 } }
  );

  if (!res.ok) return undefined;
  return res.json();
}
```

```
import getAllVehicles from "@/lib/getAllVehicles";
import { VehicleCard } from "./VehicleCard";
import Link from "next/link";

export default async function HomeMainBody() {
  const userData: Promise<Vehicle[]> = getAllVehicles();
  const vehicles = await userData;

  const content = (
    <div>
      <section className="container-fluid">
        <div className="row row-cols-sm-1 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-3 g-4">
          {vehicles.map((vehicle) => {
            return (
              <>
                <VehicleCard vehicle={vehicle} />
                <Link href={`/vehicles/${vehicle._id}`}>{vehicle.name}</Link>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );

  return content;
}
```

```
type Props = {
  promise: Promise<Vehicle[]>;
};

export default async function VehicleDetails({ promise }: Props) {
  const vehicles = await promise;

  const content = vehicles.map((vehicle) => {
    return (
      <article key={vehicle._id}>
        <h2>{vehicle.name}</h2>
      </article>
    );
  });
  return content;
}
```

```
import getVehicleDetail from "@/lib/getVehicleDetails";
import VehicleDetails from "./components/VehicleDetails";

type Params = {
  params: {
    vehicleId: string;
  };
};

export default function VehiclePage({ params: { vehicleId } }: Params) {
  const vehicleData: Promise<Vehicle[]> = getVehicleDetail(vehicleId);
  return <VehicleDetails promise={vehicleData} />;
}
```

always lead to a 404. They type keys are regular identifiers, I tried to change them to strings to see if it works but VSCode always formats them back to regular identifiers on save so I have to work with the keys as regular identifiers. Apart from the 404, it doesn't display any other error.

```
type Vehicle = {
  _id: number;
  name: string;
  pictures: string;
  description: string;
  colour: string;
  transmission: string;
  type: string;
  seat: number;
  price: number;
  date: string;
  createdBy: string;
};
```